# What are the associations for this model set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know how to set up this association between a few models. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. There are four models total. I posted a mockup of what I am thinking about for the UI at the bottom of the page, since a picture is worth 1000 words.

#### Events

There are `Events`. An event can be a party or a graduation or whatever.

#### Positions

Each event can have many `Positions`. A position is what people will be hired for. If there are 5 open positions on an event, that means they are looking to have 5 people work the event.

#### Jobs

Each position can have many `Jobs` associated with it. A job can be *cook*, *waiter*, *DJ* or whatever. So an event planner can specify that a position (e.g. person) will need to fulfill any number of jobs. One position might need to act as both a waiter and a cook. Another position might just be a bartender. Etc.

Jobs will be a look up table; event planners will select from a list of pre-existing jobs. They do not get to create their own records.

#### Specialties

Each job has many specialties. A bartender could have specialties for *Beer*, *Wine*, *Flair*, etc. A cook can have specialties for *Italian* or *Mexican*, etc.

Specialties will also be a look up table; event planners will select from a list of pre-existing specialties. They can select any number of specialties required for the position. They do not get to create their own specialties records.

#### Conclusion

I've tried a couple of variations but they aren't saving out the way I thought they would. I think `Job` should `has_and_belongs_to_many` with `Positions` but I have no idea what specialties should be. Specialties need to `belong_to` `Jobs` for the look up table but they also need to be selected per-job, per-position. **How should the associations be setup between these items to make the best use of Rails' automated awesomeness?**

#### Mockup UI

(It's mocked up in XCode/Interface builder, but I assure you, this is a Ruby on Rails site)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` I just use a `has_many :xxx, through: :join_table`. That way you can control the JoinTable.

### Event.rb

```
has_many :positions
```

### Position.rb

```
has_many :jobs
belongs_to :event
```

### Job.rb

```
has_many :specialities, through: "JobSpecialties"
has_many :position_jobs
# belongs_to :position -- no longer needed
```

### Specialty.rb

```
has_many :jobs, through: "JobSpecialites
```

### JobSpecialty.rb

```
belongs_to :specialties
belongs_to :jobs
```

### PositionJob.rb

```
belongs_to :position
belongs_to :job
has_many :specialties, through: :position_job_specialties
```

### PositionJobSpecialty.rb

```
belongs_to :position_job
belongs_to :speciality
```

You would need to create some sort of validation to ensure that the specialties you select correspond with those that belong to the selected job in PositionJob.rb

EDIT: Added more classes after reading the spec a little more closely.

Comment: Would `Job` still be able to be a lookup table at like this? In other words, if two separate positions used a `Cook`, wouldnt this cause two separate `Cook` records to be created in `Jobs`?

Comment: After looking at it again, you actually need 2 other wrapper classes. Something like `PositionJob.rb` and `PositionJobSpecialties.rb` because you want the specialites to be associated with the job for the lookup, and you want them to be selected in some other way.

Comment: Would those be the `through:` tables in a `has_many:___, through:___` ??